# Creating 3rd order tensors with python and numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a two 1 dimensional arrays, `a` such that `np.shape(a) == (n,)` and `b` such that `np.shape(b) == (m,)`.

I **want** to make a (3rd order) tensor `c` such that `np.shape(c) == (n,n,m,)`by doing `c = np.outer(np.outer(a,a),b)`.

But when I do this, I get:

```
>> np.shape(c) 

(n*n,m)
```

which is just a rectangular matrix. How can I make a 3D tensor like I want?

Comment: `np.outer` flattens the input as described in the docs... are you maybe searching for `np.kron`?

Comment: can you give an  example of what you want?

Comment: So it appears, through experimentation in ipython, that `np.kron(b,np.kron(a,a)).reshape(m,n,n)` gives what I wanted, although indeces are reversed. But that's clean so I'll use this I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could perhaps use `np.multiply.outer` instead of `np.outer` to get the required outer product:

```
>>> a = np.arange(4)
>>> b = np.ones(5)
>>> mo = np.multiply.outer
```

Then we have:

```
>>> mo(mo(a, a), b).shape
(4, 4, 5)
```

A better way could be to use `np.einsum` (this avoids creating intermediate arrays):

```
>>> c = np.einsum('i,j,k->ijk', a, a, b)
>>> c.shape
(4, 4, 5)
```

Comment: I like this better than using `np.kron` as it retains the shape information.